# Extended for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was searching for memset() for c++ and i found out some thing like this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    std::memset(a, 0, sizeof a);
    for (int ai : a) std::cout << ai;
}
```

I used for loop extended in java but never in C++. This code in running fine. I want to know how the loop in working? and how to implement in any C++ code.

Comment: The loop is looping.

Comment: They are called [range-based loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and are available since C++ 11.

Comment: didn't understand. will you please elaborate or give a link to study this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? "*how to implement in any C++ code*" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It works exactly like the same construct in Java.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of range-based loops?

Comment: There's a simple example right in your question.

Comment: You don't need memset: `int a[20]={};`.And if you really need to set some values use [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When

```
 for (int ai : a) std::cout << ai;
```

is used for array - `int a[20];` it can be substituted with

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
      std::cout << a[i];
```

or with

```
 for (int *ai = a; ai < a + (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)); ai++)
      std::cout << *ai;
```

But to work with other collection, e.g. `vector` iterators will be required:

```
std::vector<int> v(20);
// for (auto i : v) std::cout << i;
for (std::vector<int>::iterator vi = v.begin(); vi != v.end(); vi++)
    std::cout << *vi;
```